# carrying over values from one column to another in a pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

I would like to be able to carry over the Total for each month in a pivot to the next column:for instance the total calculated for each item for Jan will then be carried over to the next column as the opening inventory for Feb.  Is this possible? IF so how can it be done

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use some simple cell reference formulas, but your question is a bit vague. It looks like you want to use data from a pivot table of ending product inventory as the start of February's inventory.

If you're literally just trying to copy the contents of one cell (Your monthly totals in a Pivot Table) into another, try this:
In the cell you are looking to populate with data (We'll say Feb 1st is in cell B2, and January 31st is in cell A2), type the following : `=A2`.

This tells excel that the contents of B2 are equal to the contents of A2. You can then copy that formula throughout your sheet.  You can also do this by selecting the cell you want to populate, type =, then click on the cell you want it to equal. This is useful if you're pulling data from a pivot table, even if it's on another sheet. The formula would end up looking like this

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Pivot Table Column Header",Sheetname!$Cell,"Row Label","Row Item")`